# Настроить contact form 7 в wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины, contact-form7

Приветствую!

Подаскажите, пожалуйста, как можно в плагине contact form 7 в wordpress поменять поле "От кого"?

Сейчас приходят письма в поле от кого со значением почтового ящика магазина, хотелось бы, чтобы письмо приходило новым каждый раз, как от разного клиента. То есть чтобы в поле от кого подставлялся емайл, который вводит клиент в форме. Может надо где-то в самом коде править. Буду рад Вашим советом:)

В полях ниже вы можете использовать эти почтовые-тэги:

```
[text-389][email-704][tel-946][text-10][textarea-856]
```

В поле `From` я пишу `Email: [email-704]` - пишет Использован некорректный синтаксис почтового адреса. Мне нужно чтобы почтовый ящик отправителя был почтовым ящиком, который вводит пользователь в форму.

Comment: Поставьте туда [my-email] - то поле, которое указано в форме, как email пользователя

Comment: А где этот файл находится в котором надо поменять?) Я только начал пользоваться wordpress

Comment: Это в админке, настройках contact form 7

Comment: Завтра утром покажу картинку

Comment: @KAGG Design Супер, большое спасибо!

Comment: @KAGG Design Можете в ответе глянуть комментарии и на основе них подсказать.

Comment: Да вам @SeVlad уже все написал

Comment: @KAGG Design Не работает так

Comment: В поле `From` я пишу `Reply-To: [your-email]` - пишет Использован некорректный синтаксис почтового адреса. Мне нужно чтобы почтовый ящик отправителя было почтовым ящиком, который вводит пользователь в форму.

Comment: А пишет "некорректный" потому что поле email у вас не обязательное. Отметьте его звездочкой, все будет ок

Comment: Не корректный - потому что не тот индентификатор.`Reply-To: [email-704]` нужно писать. А во from - мылоадрес  в домене сайта, а не идентификаторы.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вам нужно указать поле email со звездочкой, как обязательное. Иначе вы будете получать указанную вами ошибку синтаксиса.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На вкладке "Письмо" укажите в поле "Дополнительные заголовки" Reply-To: и тот же тэг, что и на вкладке "Шаблон формы". В моем примере это [your-email].

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почта приходит с полем "Reply To", с адресом, указанный в форме. При нажатии кнопки "Ответить" в таком письме, открывается окно с адресом ответа, указанным пользователем в форме:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И ответ уйдет конкретному клиенту. Собственно, это и было вашей целью, насколько я понимаю.

**P.S.**

Само письмо, как видим, имеет отправителем WordPress и адрес сайта. Никакими силами легально нельзя сделать так, чтобы в поле From: стоял электронный адрес клиента. Это подмена отправителя, и все современные почтовые системы вроде gmail или yandex немедленно отправляют такое письмо в спам.

Comment: Спасибо) Мне нужно только, чтобы от кого было в почтовом ящике от введенного емайла в форме, а не от WordPress, иначе gmail делает все письма в одну пачку и через специальную программу я не могу импортировать все письма. Надо, чтобы каждое письмо приходило, как новое. А может можно подмену сделать через код сам?

Comment: @Дима, не от "wordpress", а от мыла с адреса твоего домена. какой ты там пропишешь  адрес до `@` - дело твоё. Но некоторые хостеры могут не попустить если этот адрес не заведён у них на почт сервере.

Comment: Надеюсь Вы меня поняли, что в поле от кого должен попадать адрес емайла, который введет пользователь в форме обратной свзяи например на сайте.

Comment: > Никакими силами легально нельзя сделать так, чтобы в поле From: стоял электронный адрес клиента.

Comment: Вы понимаете - никакими силами. Иначе я смог бы рассылать письма от вашего имени (зная ваш email).

Comment: @KAGGDesign На самом деле некоторые хостеры (и таких немало) позволяют это делать. Но не позволяет CF7. Хотя есть и плагины ОС  которые не проверяют FROM. Это потенциально опасные плаги. CF7 рулит :)

Comment: @SeVlad я говорю - легально. Такая почта 100% улетит в спам гугла

Comment: @Дима, нужно ориентироваться не ОТ КОГО (from).а АДРЕС ДЛЯ ОТВЕТА (REPLY-TO). Это тех заголовки они показывают не человека обрабатывающего тексты, а машины-программы, отправляющие и принимающие почту.

Comment: @KAGGDesign у гугла - 99%. У меня проходили когда-то (хотя вроде недавно они ужесточили правила. Может уже и 100). а вот к маилру даже в спам не попадёт. :)

Comment: Понял, спасибо Вам большое за помощь) Сегодня буду пробовать:)

Answer (score 2):

> Подаскажите, пожалуйста, как можно в плагине contact form 7 в
>   wordpress поменять поле "От кого"?

В доп. заголовке прописать

```
Reply-To: [your-email]
```

Где `[your-email]` идентификатор поля, прописанный в шаблоне формы.
Собсно, так оно и есть по умолчанию.

См https://contactform7.com/setting-up-mail/

---

**Д**обавка после уточнения вопроса.

> В полях ниже вы можете использовать эти почтовые-тэги:
>
> `[text-389][email-704][tel-946][text-10][textarea-856]`
>
> В поле From я пишу Email: [email-704]

В данном случае в доп заголовке нужно написать `Reply-To: [email-704]`, а во `From` использовать адрес в домене сайта, а не идентификатор.

Comment: То есть теперь имя отправителя в письме будет казать емайл, который он введет?

Comment: У меня пишет так: В полях ниже вы можете использовать эти почтовые-тэги:
`[text-389][email-704][tel-946][text-10][textarea-856]`

Comment: В поле от кого стоит - `test.ru <wordpress@test.ru>`. Вместо этого всего вписать просто `[email-704]`?

Comment: В поле `From` я пишу `Reply-To: [your-email]` - пишет Использован некорректный синтаксис почтового адреса. Мне нужно чтобы почтовый ящик отправителя был почтовым ящиком, который вводит пользователь в форму.

Comment: А если прописать в доп. заголовке - `Reply-To: [your-email]` бесполезно.

Comment: В твоём случае нужно писать `Reply-To: [email-704]`

Comment: Я писал так `Reply-To: [email-704]`, точно так же пишет, что не корректно.

Comment: Значит в шаблоне форме что-то не так. Создай новую форму. КФ7 сам всё пропишет как надо.

Comment: Если сделать по Вашему, то письмо будет приходить каждый раз, как новое в gmail? А то сейчас так как отправитель сам сайт, в gmail все делается в пачку (все новые письма за день), что очень плохо.

Comment: В жмейле итак всё валить всё в кучу. Нам нет папок. Но есть метки.  А ВП не причём. С сервера может (должно) отправляться ТОЛЬКО с домена сайта. Это в целях безопасности. Если какой-то хостер позволяет отправителя (from) подставить любого - это дыра. http://www.opennet.ru/opennews/art.shtml?num=45779 http://www.opennet.ru/opennews/art.shtml?num=45774

Comment: Вас понял, спасибо:) А в gmail точно ни как нельзя сделать, чтобы каждое письмо было, как новым? Просто я через специальную программу импортирую письма и на основе письма делаю анкету клиента. Сейчас то что целая пачка налетает за день, не получается импортировать письма по отдельности, эта вся пачка импортируется одним письмом, остальные приходится в ручную прописывать в программе(

Comment: Так новое письмо и будет.